# Creating an element inside class which is part of included html using javascript *no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, external, appendchild

I'm trying to load some HTML code through a **XMLHttpRequest** into my index.html. But I'm blocked by appending the received HTML code to another tag in my index.html.

This is my index.html with the XMLHttprequest:

```
<header id="header"></header>

<script>
    if (document.body.contains(document.getElementById('header'))) {
        var reqHeader = new XMLHttpRequest();
        reqHeader.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('header').appendChild(this.responseText);
        }
        reqHeader.open('get', 'header.html', true);
        reqHeader.send();
    }
</script>
```

And this the content of my header.html file:

```
<div id="headerWrapper">
    <ul>
        <li id="foo">1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: just use `headerContent` class in your code instead of `headerBlock`

Comment: problem is I am not able to target any of element that is present inside included file. When I put the content of included file in my index that it is working.
Might be problem is that i have included the external file with XMLHttpRequest and it is not letting me target the inside of it using js.

Comment: Either I can include file using XMLHttpRequest
or I can used above code. Is there any way I can do both

Comment: The response of the XMLHttpRequest is a string. You should then be able to parse this string using the javascript DOMParser to load the content into a DOM object. Afterwards you can access data in the DOM object as usual with getElementById etc. There is only a pre-condition: the included file has to be a valid XML, meaning only one root node.

Comment: @Uchendu this is want i needed. after putting some effort i finally able to get my included html file to target using javascript with help of DOMParser. Thanks

Comment: @SanjaySingh I'm glad I could help. Feel free to write a quick answer with your solution yourself to help other people that will search for the same problem later!

Comment: @Uchendu after using DOMParser javascript is still not able to target elements inside of included files. I get the html string as elements but not able to target those elements,Would be great if you could help I think the problemis the way I amusing DOMParser.

Comment: This is what I have done so far
`var reqHeader = new XMLHttpRequest();`
        `reqHeader.onload = function() {`
        `var htmlString = this.responseText;`
        `const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');`
        `document.getElementById('header').appendChild(parser.querySelector('#headerWrapper'));}`
        `reqHeader.open('get', 'includes/header.html', true);`
        `reqHeader.send();`

Comment: #foo is inside included file
 `document.getElementById('foo').classList.add('test');`
and this line of code is not excuting.

Comment: @SanjaySingh I'm a bit lost. Please update your question. Provide a clear structure of the concerned code, separate the different files and indicate the names. In the best case, you could provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/) example. Then I can get an overview about the problem

Comment: @Uchendu I can not share my code through jsfiddle or sandbox as it is a structural based query. [query DOMParser](https://www.filedropper.com/querydomparser) . Here is a zip attached. when you will run it, a console error generated for classlist. please check if I have implemented the domParser correctly or not.

Comment: @SanjaySingh your solution works actually. There must be another problem (probably cross origin policy or similar). Check out my answer which contains a runnable minimal solution version where I stripped out the XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210571/discussion-between-uchendu-and-sanjay-singh).

Answer (score 2):

The content returned by the XMLHttpRequest is a String. You can parse that String using the javascript [XMLParser](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_parser.asp), which will returns you a DOM element that you can access with usual javascript DOM accessing syntax.

So in your XMLHttpRequest, use the following code

```
const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
document.getElementById('header').appendChild(parser.querySelector('#headerWrapper'));
```

Simplified example without XMLHttpRequest because of cross origin policy:

```js
if (document.body.contains(document.getElementById('header'))) {
    var htmlString = '<div id="headerWrapper"><ul><li id="foo">1</li><li id="bar">2</li></ul></div>';
    const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
    document.getElementById('header').appendChild(parser.querySelector('#headerWrapper'));
}

document.getElementById('foo').classList.add('test');
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header id="header"></header>
</body>

</html>
```